# Creating a random number of variables, and then summing over them

Tags: r

New to R, and would like to find a nice way to accomplish the following:

Letting `n` be some integer that the user inputs, I created `n` variables using the following code:

```
for(i in 1:n) assign(paste0("phi1", i), i)
```

to get `n` variables named `phi11`, `phi12`, and so on until `phi1n`. In the code above, `phi1i = i`, but in my actual program this is a much more complicated function of `i`.

Now I would like to find a nice way to sum the values of all these variables. But since `n` is a user-chosen integer, and since I have no easy way of looping over all these variables, I'm not sure how to go about this in a nice way.

Comment: You should consider using a list of variables, rather than using the environment in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating objects with special names, you can use a list.  Then it is easy to work on them as a collection.

For example,

```
l <- lapply(seq(n), function(i) { i })
```

Then to find the sum, you can use:

```
sum(unlist(l))
```